# Adding values to a vector using for loop

Tags: r, loops, indexing, variable-assignment

I have a list named `mylist` that has character elements in it which I'm trying to merge and save in another object.
The following piece of code:

```
result <- c()
for (i in length(mylist)) {
  temp <- paste(mylist[[i]][2], mylist[[i]][3], mylist[[i]][4], sep="")
  result[i] <- temp
}
result
```

Results in the following output:

```
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

Why am I getting NA's instead of the merged characters for EVERY `result[i]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the unexpected result has already been explained by [Brent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60981773/3817004) and [damir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60982188/3817004).

However, I suggest to use `seq_along(mylist)` as it is more safe than `1:length(mylist)` in case `mylist` is empty for some reason.

```
result <- c()
for (i in seq_along(mylist)) {
  result[i] <- paste(mylist[[i]][2:4], collapse = "")
}
result
```

> ```
> [1] "BCD" "CDE" "DEF" "EFG" "FGH"
> ```

If `mylist` is empty, `length(mylist)` would become 0 but the loop would be executed twice for `1:0`.

In addition, the `collapse` parameter tells `paste()` to concatenate the elements of a vector thereby saving a lot of typing.

By the way, the same result can be achieved by using `sapply()`:

```
sapply(mylist, function(x) paste(x[2:4], collapse = ""))
```

> ```
> [1] "BCD" "CDE" "DEF" "EFG" "FGH"
> ```

#### Data

The OP has not provided a reproducible example but says that he has "a list named `mylist` that has character elements". So, here are some made-up data:

```
mylist <- lapply(1:5, function(i) LETTERS[i + (0:3)])

mylist
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
>
> [[2]]
> [1] "B" "C" "D" "E"
>
> [[3]]
> [1] "C" "D" "E" "F"
>
> [[4]]
> [1] "D" "E" "F" "G"
>
> [[5]]
> [1] "E" "F" "G" "H"
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation as well as showing better ways to do this, you're great!

Answer (score 0):

`length(myList)` is just a scalar value (i.e., a single value). You need to add the starting value like this: `1:length(myList)`. I am guessing that the last value in myList has some result?

Answer (score 0):

Your loop only starts and ends at `length(myList)`, because the value of `i` is always `length(myList)`. So, your loop "loops" only once. 
To change this, you need to specify the start and end value of `i`. Something like, 
`for (i in 1:length(myList))`